# How to prevent Visual Studio 2022 reformatting on uncommenting a block?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

How do I prevent Visual Studio 2022 reformatting on uncommenting a block ?

I use `Ctrl+/` to (un)comment a line - everything stays the same. But try doing the same with multiple lines and VS suddenly reformats them for some reason.

**Note**: I know `Ctrl+z` will undo this (if executed immediately) but months of practice and needless frustration suggests that this is not sufficient as one have more important things on their mind than having to remember this quirk.

> code formatting settings:
> [image: c# code formatting settings]]

> installed extensions:
> [image: installed extensions]

Comment: Is it better with `Ctrl + k + c` and `Ctrl + k + u` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the result is still the same

Comment: Maybe unpopular but set the formatting rules of VS to something that fits your habits so that formatting after uncommenting fits that and isn't a problem?

Comment: @Ralf Hard pill to swallow - I disabled all auto formatting and wanted to keep it that way.

Comment: Any extensions installed that also fiddle with formatting?

Comment: @Ralf No, nothing obvious https://i.stack.imgur.com/25lHV.png (disabling HLSL ext changed nothing as well)

Comment: Since `Ctrl+Z` does undo the format operation, that means the C# language service is doing formatting as a separate edit from the Uncomment operation.  If you can't find a way to turn it off, send feedback through VS or try reporting it at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn.

Comment: Good idea. I reported it via VS feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You might have auto formatting enabled, or an .editorconfig that enables it.

It's different for each language. You can check the ones you use:
Tools->Options->Text Editor->Your language->Code style->Formatting

There you might have options enabled like "Automatically format when I do XYZ"

Comment: Thank you for your response. Not using `.editorconfig`. I made sure all [Formatting options are disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCWE5.png) but there seems to be no toggle in formatting settings to modify this specific behavior.